# ReCAPTCHA plugin on word press

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha

How can I translate ReCAPTCHA plugin on word press as I want it to be in Arabic in translated pages.
I couldn't reach it's files to edit language

Answer (score 1):

**This is your link to cdn look at the end, hl parameter**

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=myCallBack&render=explicit&hl=fr" async defer></script>
```

This is your captcha inside the form

```
<div id="recaptcha1"></div>
```

This is your javascript you can specify the lang code here too, I assume one of them is enough

```
var recaptcha1;
var myCallBack = function() {
    //Render the recaptcha1 on the element with ID "recaptcha1"
    recaptcha1 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha1', {
    'sitekey': '6LdJLws_your site key',
    'lang' : 'fr'
   });};
```

[Check Language code here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/language)

[JavaScript resource (api.js) parameters](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_param)

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help.
But I still not able to reach the file which has this code  
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=myCallBack&render=explicit&hl=fr" async defer></script>

Comment: just find in your code "recaptcha/api.js" or if this one plugin then provide plugin name & version

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with WordPress plugin. You can use -

[Google Captcha (reCAPTCHA) by BestWebSoft](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-captcha/)

Otherwise @ravi patel is suggesting good in above answer.

Comment: I already used a Plugin but I am not able to reach the files to edit language

Comment: for this plugin as per latest you can customize here :

lang     = $( this ).attr( 'data-lang' ),

Comment: Thanks a lot , but do you know where it for this plugin " WordPress ReCaptcha Integration "